# unfortunately has stopped app android when run with emulator

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am new to android app development( from yesterday only i started to learn android ).

Then when i run emulator, it gives a message "unfortunately has stopped", please help me solve this error

MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace MediaPlayer.Android
{
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        try
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

    }
}
}
```

main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:background="@drawable/background">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64.2dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="72.7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3.6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mix" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="72.7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3.6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="72.7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_setup"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3.6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cog" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="72.7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_mix"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3.6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/settings" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_volumn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3.6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/volum" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50.9dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Toi la Text"
        android:layout_width="322.6dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nameSong" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_feedback"
        android:background="@drawable/feedback" />
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="276.5dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:background="@drawable/monkey"
    android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46.5dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65.1dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="72.7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_mix"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3.6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mix" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="72.7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_gobot"
        android:layout_marginRight="4.8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gobot" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="72.7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_play"
        android:layout_marginRight="6.0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/smiley" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="72.7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_gotop"
        android:layout_marginRight="4.8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gotop" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="72.7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:background="@drawable/refresh" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

log

```
10-08 01:50:30.429 D/AndroidRuntime( 3064): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-08 01:50:30.439 D/AndroidRuntime( 3064): CheckJNI is ON
10-08 01:50:30.559 D/dalvikvm( 3064): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
10-08 01:50:30.829 D/dalvikvm( 3064): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
10-08 01:50:31.519 E/memtrack( 3064): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-08 01:50:31.519 E/android.os.Debug( 3064): failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-08 01:50:33.869 E/memtrack( 3076): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-08 01:50:33.869 E/android.os.Debug( 3076): failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-08 01:50:41.419 E/memtrack( 3094): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-08 01:50:41.419 E/android.os.Debug( 3094): failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-08 01:50:41.789 D/AndroidRuntime( 3094): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
10-08 01:50:41.869 W/ActivityManager(  357): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/MediaPlayer.Android-Signed.apk
10-08 01:50:41.939 W/ActivityManager(  357): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/MediaPlayer.Android-Signed.apk
10-08 01:50:49.109 E/memtrack( 3116): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-08 01:50:49.109 E/android.os.Debug( 3116): failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-08 01:50:49.649 E/libEGL  (   54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
10-08 01:50:49.659 E/libEGL  (   54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
10-08 01:50:49.659 E/libEGL  (   54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
10-08 01:50:49.659 E/libEGL  (   54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
10-08 01:50:49.659 E/SurfaceFlinger(   54): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 1488669638
10-08 01:50:49.659 E/SurfaceFlinger(   54): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
10-08 01:50:49.659 E/libEGL  (   54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
10-08 01:50:49.659 E/libEGL  (   54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
10-08 01:50:49.729 W/WindowManager(  357): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (218x272) to layer 21005
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): Process: MediaPlayer.Android, PID: 3127
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_22 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): 
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4777)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4309)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_22 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:38)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4774)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): ... 12 more
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Xamarin.Android.Platform
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:227)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:32)
10-08 01:50:50.879 E/AndroidRuntime( 3127): ... 13 more
10-08 01:50:58.029 D/AndroidRuntime( 3145): 
10-08 01:50:58.029 D/AndroidRuntime( 3145): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-08 01:50:58.039 D/AndroidRuntime( 3145): CheckJNI is ON
10-08 01:50:58.139 D/AndroidRuntime( 3149): 
10-08 01:50:58.139 D/AndroidRuntime( 3149): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-08 01:50:58.149 D/AndroidRuntime( 3149): CheckJNI is ON
10-08 01:50:58.439 D/dalvikvm( 3149): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
10-08 01:50:58.819 D/dalvikvm( 3145): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
10-08 01:50:58.969 D/dalvikvm( 3149): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
10-08 01:50:59.639 E/WindowManager(  357): Starting window AppWindowToken{b40d66c8 token=Token{b3ebe528 ActivityRecord{b40495f8 u0 MediaPlayer.Android/mediaplayer.android.TrialSplashScreen t18}}} timed out
10-08 01:51:00.269 I/Choreographer(  357): Skipped 110 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-08 01:51:00.609 E/memtrack( 3145): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-08 01:51:00.609 E/android.os.Debug( 3145): failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-08 01:51:00.849 E/memtrack( 3149): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-08 01:51:00.849 E/android.os.Debug( 3149): failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-08 01:51:01.579 D/AndroidRuntime( 3145): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
10-08 01:51:01.639 I/ActivityManager(  357): Force stopping MediaPlayer.Android appid=10061 user=0: from pid 3145
10-08 01:51:01.659 I/ActivityManager(  357): Killing 3127:MediaPlayer.Android/u0a61 (adj 9): stop MediaPlayer.Android
```

Comment: Either OpenGL is not supported on your emulator OR you have implemented a class and forgot to implement its abstract methods.

Comment: I dont think so. because im not implement every thing in my code.
I'm designing GUI.

Comment: Somebody help me. plzzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "unfortunately has stopped" is a general message meaning that there was *some* unhandled exception.

Now, looking at your log you can find that your program crashes with the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application
>   Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_22 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!

This is, of course, more meaningful.
Here (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10159/can-no-longer-run-android-applications-using-xamarin-4-2-and-xamarin-android-4-10-1) you can find discussion of similar problem.
The solution proposed there is to change your csproj file manually:
from

`<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>True</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>`

to

```
<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>False</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
```

I think you should try this.